# Can a magnetically levitating sphere spin in any direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, levitation

I am trying to design a system that levitates a sphere (ball). I have found several solutions, however, it seems to me that the levitating ball only has one degree of freedom, i.e. rotation around the vertical axis.

Q: Can I design a system which enables rotation of the ball around any axis, i.e. to have 3 rotational degrees of freedom?

Comment: Do you mean "more than one degree of freedom _at the same time_"?

Comment: @AlexDoe Yes, more than one DoF at the same time

Comment: Even thou your question may be more suitable for engineering SE, my opinion is that there really is just one degree of freedom for a simple magnetically levitating sphere  (or any other shape for that matter). Changing the axis of rotation would flip the polarity of the magnetic ball. Maybe more complex non magnetic "ball" with a gyroscopic magnet inside?